# Renaming App and new App Icon - What are the Best Practices?

Tags: android, ios

I have an Android an Android Mobile Application with a good userbase . Lets say the name is "A". I wanted to change the Icon as well as the Name (to say "B"). What are the best practices here? Should I first update the icon followed by another release with name change?

I do not have any push notification framework. Hence if an user suddenly doesnt see the old app and icon (since app autoupdated)  he might get confused and keep searching in local search of Android phone and coudnt find.

Answer (score 0):

Just name it `B formerly A`. Your users can find your app searching for `A`. 
Then a few months later remove the `formerly A` from to name. So you give people some time to get used to the new name.

Comment: Thanks - but not sure if that is a good user experience . And long names may not be right